# Are any permissions required to backup a mysql table through php script

Tags: php, mysql

I want to take back up of mysql database table in sql file through php script.

I am using below code.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'backupfile.sql' FROM tablename");
```

It gives me following error :

```
Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

The 'username' has these permissions :

```
SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, INDEX, CREATE, ALTER, DROP, LOCK TABLES, REFERENCES, CREATE ROUTINE, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES
```

I just want to know is there any extra permission required to execute `select * into outfile` and same for the `LOAD DATA INFILE 'filename' INTO TABLE tablename`.

Comment: No, There is no problem while connecting to the database. Even I have tried by running another query with same database and same connection parameters in the same script, All is working fine except "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE"

Comment: ah, fair enough - I thought I remembered a different error when you try to do something outside your privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the [FILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file) privilege to use [SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html#id902164), since the command will create a file *on the MySQL server host*.

I also think your query is wrong. This should be the right order according to the manual:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename INTO OUTFILE 'backupfile.sql';
```

Comment: With one special side effect for the FILE privilege, it's a privilege that should be allowed for the **whole database server**, it cannot be applied only to one database.

Comment: regilero, good point. The FILE privilege should only be given to server administrators, since it give access to write and read files on the server.

Comment: You are right. I need the FILE privilege.
But the query I am using is right. Rgith syntex for back up a talbe is as following :
"SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'backupFile.sql' FROM tableName"

Comment: oh, means I could not have FILE privilege.
Actually I want to copy whole table from one database to another database using php script by storing the back up file at host server side and then importing it in another database.
Now what should I do ?
Which also should not be very time consuming.

Comment: Is the databases on the same machine? In that case, you may be interested in `CREATE TABLE newdb.tablename SELECT * FROM olddb.tablename;` If they're on different machines, write (or find) a PHP script to create a SQL dump file for you.